Unity animation has double-stacked frames
Im making a 2d pixel art game in unity. My animations look like 2 frames are playing at once. This image shows an example. You'll notice around the head the pixels look pretty weird, the neck has a weird shadow under it, the lips have the same, and the scarf has weird edges and the center looks too dark. In general some pixels are too big and some are too small. 
If you need any more info please write a comment and i will try to provide more.

just as a note - it works fine in scene view but when i click play this happens


Only use integer multiples of image resolution 2. Don't scale the game view. 3. Watch this video if both 1 and 2 don't work: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d6tp43wZqps

